# $Ext(-,\mathbb Z)$ for profinite (Galois) groups

Tags: galois-theory, homological-algebra, profinite-groups

I start from the vague question "how should a Galois group behave"?

For example, what can be said for $Ext^1(G,\mathbb Z)$ when $G$ is a Galois group? And what about the behaviour of $Ext^1(G,A)$ for $A$ an arbitrary (abelian?) group?

This is actually still a vague question, perhaps, but I was interested in knowing any relationships between the homological point of view (so $Ext$, but potentially any interesting functor on groups) and the fact of "being or not Galois", and I coundn't find them anywhere. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Galois groups have a topology and it's not clear a priori how to incorporate that topology when computing Ext; note that the category of topological abelian groups is not an abelian category, so there's no obvious abelian category which includes both $\mathbb{Z}$ and, say, the Galois group $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$. (I assume you're using abelian Galois groups; I don't know what Ext could mean otherwise.)

Comment: It's not true that $\operatorname{Ext}^1(G,\Bbb Z)=0$ for finite (abelian) groups. For example, for $G=\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, we have $\operatorname{Ext}^1(G,\Bbb Z)=\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. In fact, the only finite abelian group $G$ such that $\operatorname{Ext}^1(G, \Bbb Z)=0$ is the trivial group.